# JavaScript (Node.JS 10) RegEx to Extract Variable Number of Words over Multiple Lines

Tags: javascript, node.js, regex, drools

**Input**:

```
template header
company
subCompany
package dummyRule;
template "dummy-rule"
rule "dummy-rule"
when
  eval(true)
then
System.out.println("Hello World");
end
end template
```

There can be any number of words & empty lines between `template header` & `package`. Only words between `template header` & `package` are needed as output.

**Expected Output**:

```
Group 1: company
Group 2: subCompany
Group 3: (next word)
& so on...
```

**What I Tried**:

`template header(\s+(\w+))+`

https://regex101.com/r/O2d41R/3

**Actual Result**:

```
Group 1:  dummyRule
Group 2: dummyRule
```

Comment: what about firstly `replace`ing `\n` with `''`?

Comment: Your `template header(\s+(\w+))+` pattern has **two** capturing groups, so you only have **two**groups. Repeated capturing groups always keep the last value matched in the last iteration.